# Find a fixed length path of adjacent 2D array elements

Tags: arrays, list, search, path, tree

I have a `m x m` two-dimensional array and I want to randomly select a sequence of `n` elements. The elements have to be adjacent (not diagonally). What is a good approach here? I though about a depth-first search from a random starting point but that seemed a little bit overkill for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right, you are looking for sequence like continuous numbers ?

When i simplyfy this:

9 4 3

0 7 2

5 6 1

So when the 1 is selected, you'd like to have path from 1 to 4 right ? I personally think that Depth-First search would be the best choice. It's not that hard, it's actually pretty simple. Imagine you select number 2. You'll remember position of number 2 and then you can look for lowest numbers until there are any. When you are done with this part, you just do the same for higher numbers.

You have two stacks one for possible ways and another one for final path.
When going through the array, you are just poping from possibilities and pushing right ones into the final stack.
The best approach would be finding the lowest possible number without saving anything and then just looking for higher numbers and storing them so at the end you'll get stack from the highest number to the lowest.

If I get that wrong and you mean just like selecting elements that are "touching" like (from my table) 9 0 7 6, which means that the content doesn't matter, then you can do it simple by picking one number, storing all possibilities (every element around it) and then pick random number from 0 to size of that stored values. When you select one, you remove it from these stored values but you keep them. Then you run this on the new element and you just add these new elements to stored elements so the random will always pick surrounding around these selected numbers.

Comment: The values of the array entries don't matter. They can be objects aswell so there are no weights. I like the idea with the two stacks, thanks a lot!